# Assigning Group No. based on Rolling time window - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with stock prices:

```
 Dates       Price

2019-02-01     52
2019-02-02     51
2019-02-03     53
2019-02-04     55
...            ...
2019-08-01     49
2019-08-02     48
2019-08-03     52
```

Now I want to create new column which basically assigns or updates the group value every 6 months. Desired Dataframe:

```
  Dates       Price    Group

2019-02-01     52        1
2019-02-02     51        1
2019-02-03     53        1
2019-02-04     55        1
...           ...       ...
2019-08-01     49        2
2019-08-02     48        2
2019-08-03     52        2
```

The values of the `group` column needs to be based on the first month value of the dataframe. So if the month of the first row is 04, then Group 1 will be from 04-09 months and 10-03 should be group 2 and so on. I want the values to be updated based on a 6-month time window gap. Haven't been able to find a solution for this yet.

P.S. I want the group nos. to be increasing and not repetitive, for ex:

```
Dates        Price    group

2018-08-01    50        1
...          ...       ...
2019-01-01    55        1
...          ...       ...
2019-02-01    60        2
...          ...       ...
2019-07-01    56        2
2019-08-01    57        3
...          ...       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have daily data for every consecutive day, you can use [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) and integer division:

```
# If necessary
# df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

df['group'] = (df['Dates'].dt.to_period('M').factorize()[0] // 6) + 1
```

Otherwise, you can create the groups using [`pandas.period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) first, then [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
periods = pd.period_range(df['Dates'].min(), df['Dates'].max(), freq='M')
period_groups = pd.Series((pd.factorize(periods)[0] // 6 + 1), index=periods)

df['group'] = df['Dates'].dt.to_period('M').map(period_groups)
```

---

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['2018-08-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01'], 'Price': [50, 55, 60, 56, 57], 'group': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

periods = pd.period_range(df['Dates'].min(), df['Dates'].max(), freq='M')
period_groups = pd.Series((pd.factorize(periods)[0] // 6 + 1), index=periods)

df['group_2'] = df['Dates'].dt.to_period('M').map(period_groups)
```

[out]

```
       Dates  Price  group  group_2
0 2018-08-01     50      1        1
1 2019-01-01     55      1        1
2 2019-02-01     60      2        2
3 2019-07-01     56      2        2
4 2019-08-01     57      3        3
```